# Trouble finding links in very large string

Tags: string, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping baseball reference for a data science project, and have come a cross an issue when trying to scrape player data from a specific league. A league that jsut started playing this season. When I scrape old leagues that have already finished playing I have no issues. But I want to scrape the league at this link: https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/league.cgi?id=c346199a live as the season goes. However the links are hidden behind a lot of what seem to be plain text. So BeautifulSoup.find_all('a', href = True) does not work.

So instead here is what my thought process has been so far.

```
html = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/league.cgi?id=c346199a').text, features = 'html.parser').find_all('div')
ind = [str(div) for div in html][0]
orig_ind = ind[ind.find('/register/team.cgi?id='):]
count = orig_ind.count('/register/team.cgi?id=')

team_links = []
for i in range(count):
  # rn finds the same one over and over
  link = orig_ind[orig_ind.find('/register/team.cgi?id='):orig_ind.find('title')].strip().replace('"', '')
  # try to remove it from orig_ind and do the next link...
  # this is the part that is not working rn
  orig_ind = orig_ind.replace(link, '')
  team_links.append('https://baseball-reference.com' + link)
```

Which outputs:

```
['https://baseball-reference.com/register/team.cgi?id=71fe19cd',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
 'https://baseball-reference.com',
```

and so on. I am trying to get all of the team links from this page: https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/league.cgi?id=c346199a

and then crawl over to the player links on each of those pages and collect some data. Like I said it works on pretty much every single league I have ever tried on except for this one.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tables you see on this site is stored inside HTML comments (`<!-- ... -->`) so BeautifulSoup normally doesn't see them. To parse them try next example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment


soup = BeautifulSoup(
    requests.get(
        "https://www.baseball-reference.com/register/league.cgi?id=c346199a"
    ).text,
    features="html.parser",
)

s = "".join(c for c in soup.find_all(text=Comment) if "table_container" in c)
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('[href*="/register/team.cgi?id="]'):
    print("{:<30} {}".format(a.text, a["href"]))
```

Prints:

```
Battle Creek Bombers           /register/team.cgi?id=f3c4b615
Kenosha Kingfish               /register/team.cgi?id=71fe19cd
Kokomo Jackrabbits             /register/team.cgi?id=8f1a41fc
Rockford Rivets                /register/team.cgi?id=9f4fe2ef
Traverse City Pit Spitters     /register/team.cgi?id=7bc8d111
Kalamazoo Growlers             /register/team.cgi?id=9995d2a1
Fond du Lac Dock Spiders       /register/team.cgi?id=02911efc

...and so on.
```